# Handling touches for a subview that's larger than its parent view

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, touch, subview, touchesbegan

Let's say I make a UIImageView that contains another UIImageView.  But the SubView is larger than the first view.

[image]

The green subview is significantly larger than it's superview, the black square.  If I touch in the very top left where it's only the black square, I get "touchbegan image1" which is what I would expect.  If I touch in the area where the black square and the green square overlap, i get "touchbegan image1" and "touchbegan image2" which is what I would expect.  **Here's my question:**  If I touch in the area outside of the black squares frame where only the green square exists, i get no output.  So TouchesBegan is called for neither image1 nor image2.  In this case, I want TouchesBegan to be called for image2 (Green) when I touch only the green rectangle, *while still maintaining image2 (Green) as a subview of image1 (Black)*.  Is that possible?

```
    MyImage image1 = new MyImage(new RectangleF(0,0,200,200), "image1");
    image1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
    this.View.AddSubview(image1);

    MyImage image2 = new MyImage(new RectangleF(50,50,500,500), "image2");
    image2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    image1.AddSubview(image2);




public class MyImage : UIImageView
{

    public MyImage ( RectangleF frame, string _Name ) : base(frame)
    {
        Name = _Name;
        UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    }


    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine("touchbegan " + Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you add it as a child of image1. Image1 listens for touches inside its bound/frame and send it to its child if any. image2, might be bigger, but its touchlistener comes from image1 frame touch.

Comment: Thanks. So what i'm asking is intentionally not possible?